# How mapping specific property from arraylist

Tags: javascript, list, increment

I m looking a way to get all email property from my postList list to filtering max chars authorized, the problme is i don't know really how mapping email property from postList...

```
const postList = [
 {"postId": 1, "id": 1, "email": "Eliseo@gardner.biz"},
 {"postId": 1, "id": 2, "email": "Jayne_Kuhic@sydney.com"},
 {"postId": 1, "id": 3, "email": "Nikita@garfield.biz"},
 {"postId": 1, "id": 4, "email": "Lew@alysha.tv"},
]

const onlyEmailValid = []

for (let i = 0; i < postList.length; i++) {
   if(postList.email.value.length > max_chars) {
     console.log("email : " + postList.email + " has too long");
       continue
     }
      
     onlyEmailValid.push(postList[i]);
}
console.log(clearJobList);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const postList = [
 {"postId": 1, "id": 1, "email": "Eliseo@gardner.biz"},
 {"postId": 1, "id": 2, "email": "Jayne_Kuhic@sydney.com"},
 {"postId": 1, "id": 3, "email": "Nikita@garfield.biz"},
 {"postId": 1, "id": 4, "email": "Lew@alysha.tv"},
]

const onlyEmailValid = []
const max_chars = 15 //example
for (let i = 0; i < postList.length; i++) {
   if(postList[i].email.length > max_chars) {
     console.log("email : " + postList[i].email + " has too long");
       continue
     }
      
     onlyEmailValid.push(postList[i]);
}
console.log(onlyEmailValid);
```

Comment: thank you very much u help me greatly :)

Answer (score 1):

Hello try to use `filter` method

```js
const postList = [
 {"postId": 1, "id": 1, "email": "Eliseo@gardner.biz"},
 {"postId": 1, "id": 2, "email": "Jayne_Kuhic@sydney.com"},
 {"postId": 1, "id": 3, "email": "Nikita@garfield.biz"},
 {"postId": 1, "id": 4, "email": "Lew@alysha.tv"},
]

const onlyEmailValid = []
const max_chars = 13
postList.filter(item=>{
    (item.email.length > max_chars) ? console.log("email : " + item.email + " has too long") : onlyEmailValid.push(item);
})

console.log(onlyEmailValid);
```

Comment: yeah great idea my friends, thank you ;)